# How do I display the geometric values of a spatial object in my table Microsoft SQL Sever 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

Hello I want to display the actual geometric points that make up my spatial object in MS SQL Sever 2012. I have created these spatial object from AutoCad Map 3D. I can see the tuples in the table in the SQL Sever Management Studio but when I look at the geometry attribute it is just a long hexadecimal value.

0x000000000204050000000020FBAE33B7D44000E03C21AB6AAF40009C8154327ED74000E03C21AB6AAF40009C8154327ED7400000083E3E5850400020FBAE33B7D4400000083E3E5850400020FBAE33B7D44000E03C21AB6AAF4001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF000000000A

I am looking for is:

geometry = 'POLYGON((1 1, 3 3, 3 1, 1 1))';

How do I get MS SQL Sever 2012 to return these type of values for the tuples in my table of spatial objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `STAsText()` on the resulting column. Assuming your column is called geo:

```
select geo.STAsText()
from yourTable
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, tap the check mark next to it. That gives me a small infusion of Stack Overflow reputation that I use to fuel my scheme to take over the world! Or something like that. ;)